# Do people actually say 'Quartiers de pommes de terre' ?

Tags: québec, alimentation

Before going to order lunch at Tim Horton's I went to their [french website](http://www.timhortons.com/ca/fr/menu/nutrition-et-bien-etre.php) to lookup potato wedges. It says they're called 'Quartiers de pommes de terre savoureux'. It's obvious no one is going to say savoureux when they order.

It still seems long even with just 'Quartiers de pommes de terre'. Is there an easier way to say potato wedges?

Or maybe I'm just leaving too much space between words so it feels long.

Comment: On French recipe websites the most usual term is indeed *quartiers de pommes de terre*,  [here](http://www.mafourchette.com/recettes/on-craque-pour-les-quartiers-de-pommes-de-terre-a-l-ail-et-au-parmesan) or [here](http://www.pomlorette.com/produits/decouvrez-nos-recettes/quartiers-de-pommes-de-terre-pomlorette-au-four/), you will find plenty more. Restaurants and ready made food often use *potato weges*, sometimes they use their own commercial name, in French MacDonalds they've become [Deluxe potatoes](https://www.mcdonalds.fr/produits/sauces/deluxe-potatoes).

Comment: True in France but not in Quebec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no French word for "potato wedge", because we don't have potato wedges in France. So when people wanted to introduce them here, they had to decide how to call them. Many people colloquially didn't even bother to translate. "je mangerais bien des potato wedges ce soir". And my parents would go like "wait, what?" (in French).

And of course, people started to translate, especially commercial producers. So "quartiers de pommes de terre" is not worse than anything else.

It doesn't sound French at all, though. Because neither do potato wedges.

In fact when hearing or reading "quartiers de pommes de terre", I puzzle for a fraction of a second, and then I have to mentally translate back to the true meaning: "ah!, ils parlent de potato wedges".

Comment: Il faut comprendre le contexte. Tim Horton est une entreprise canadienne et la traduction au français s'est faite en français québécois. Pour les québécois, un quartier de pomme de terre (ou plus fréquemment quartier de patate) est très compréhensible. Je ne connais personne qui aurait préféré utiliser "potato wedge". Spoken like a true French: 1) France is not the only French-speaking country 2) France not having a French word for something is actually typical of France.

Answer (score 4):

While the question is tagged Quebec, here is a France specific reply.

***Pommes de terre en quartiers*** is understandable and can be used with no problem in a recipe but I never saw it in a menu. However, the English word potatoes (without "wedges") is quickly spreading to name this dish. In fast-foods and cafeterias, I'm often given the choice between *frites* (French fries) and **potatoes**. Search the web for "recettes de potatoes" and you'll see how common this term is becoming .

Note that the reason why wedges has been dropped is that word is incomprehensible for most French people, while everyone understand potato, at least because its similarity with *patate*.

---

Bien que la question soit taguée Québec, voici une réponse spécifique à la France.

**Pommes de terre en quartiers** est compréhensible et ne pose aucun problème dans des recette de cuisine mais je ne l'ai jamais vu utilisé dans un menu. En revanche, le nom *potatoes* (sans *wedge*) est en train de s'imposer pour désigner ce plat. Il m'a souvent été proposé dans les fast-foods ou les restaurants d'entreprise le choix entre frites et *potatoes*. Recherchez "recettes de potatoes" sur le web et vous verrez comme ce terme est devenu courant.

La raison pour laquelle *wedges* n'est pas repris est que ce mot est incompréhensible pour la majorité des français alors que *potato* est compris par tout le monde en raison de la proximité avec « patate ».

Answer (score 3):

J'ai jeté un bref coup d'oeil au *Grand Larousse gastronomique* (2007), et j'ai compté à l’œil au moins dix fois le terme *quartiers* et j'en étais à peine rendu à *anchoix*. Les *quartiers de fruits, de légumes*, citrons, carottes, pommes de terre, tomates, artichauts, etc. c'est bien usuel en français, et on ne s'étonne donc pas de les retrouver autant dans l'ouvrage spécialisé de *Larousse* que dans son [dictionnaire](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quartier/65535?q=quartier#64791) en ligne (*quartier de pomme*), qu'au [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2497816) (*quartiers d'ananas séché*), que dans le parler de tous les jours quand par exemple on offre ça à un enfant etc. Au *TLFi* on parle aussi de la division naturelle d'un fruit avec l'exemple *[quartier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quartier) d'orange*. Les emplois se [développent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/quartier) depuis le 12-13<sup>e</sup>. Il est bien de préciser que les pommes de terre sont *cuites/frites* (*quartiers de pommes de terre cuites/frites*) ou de mentionner qu'il s'agit d'un plat (*plat de pommes de terre en quartiers*) afin d'éviter la confusion avec l'aliment travaillé (*en quartiers*) dans une recette par exemple. On peut aussi selon le cas comparer plus ou moins maladroitement avec les frites (... en quartiers, plus grosses et bien loin des [juliennes](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8429833), ondulées etc.). À mon avis, s'il fallait se fier à une autre langue que le français pour désigner un plat fait de simples quartiers de pommes de terre cuites, on se poserait de sérieuses questions. Dans une chaîne de restauration rapide, on peut préférer le terme au menu afin d'être compris de la personne au comptoir, et ici le terme au menu s'appuie sur un emploi bien usuel, du légume/fruit en quartiers, dont les coins plus ou moins saillants et la géométrie sont compatibles avec l'idée du [*wedge*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/wedge) qui est pour ainsi dire le point d'appui de la [patate](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2082776) du *potato wedge*.

---

Indeed, *[quartier](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quartier/65535?q=quartier#64791)(s) de* with a fruit or vegetable name is quite typical for the *quarter*, the equal/unequal piece of, and for how a fruit such as the orange naturally splits up (which looks like a wedge shape of sorts). As you noted the *savoureux* adjective is not essential here. Specifying that the [*potato wedges*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_wedges) are fried or baked dependingly (*quartiers de pommes de terres cuites/frites*) may be helpful when you're describing the dish in greater detail and the context is not as clear as with a Tim Hortons menu or people don't know much about it i.e. otherwise it may feel a bit like you're talking about a raw ingredient sliced up in a certain way from a recipe. Using the reference to a dish may help (*il s'agit d'un plat (fait) de quartiers de pommes de terre cuite*), and one can surely get away with talking about fries and their shapes and sizes...