# « Potatoes » : mode d'emploi ?

Tags: anglais, usage, prononciation, france, emprunts

Dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22395/3177) on a présenté l'emprunt [*potatoes*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/22413) en France, au pluriel, pour désigner le plat de [*potato wedges*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_wedges), et on a un [exemple](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22395/do-people-actually-say-quartiers-de-pommes-de-terre#comment43344_22395) d'une chaîne bien connue où l'on dit *les deluxe potatoes*. L'adaptation *potatoes* est une solution intéressante à la difficulté avec le *wedge*. D'autre part, on sait tout d'abord qu'on peut avoir plus d'une prononciation pour le *potato* en langue anglaise ( [/pə-ˈtā-(ˌ)tō, -tə, dial pə-ˈdā-, bə-/](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potatoes) ; [/pəˈteɪ.təʊ/ , /pəˈteɪ.t̬oʊ/](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/potato) ; [/pəˈtɑːtəʊ/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potato) etc.). De plus on sait que la prononciation reflète fortement la grammaire dans ce contexte (*-toes* : təʊ/t̬oʊ-z) contrairement à pomme(s) en français où le *s* est évidemment muet. Je m'intéresse à la prononciation et à la grammaire avec cet [emprunt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emprunt_lexical) récent.

---

- Généralement, la prononciation de *potatoes* en France suit-elle celle qu'on trouve aux États-Unis et/ou en Angleterre, ou est-elle différente et si oui à quels égards ; prononce-t-on ce pluriel de *potatoes* avec le son /z/ comme en anglais ou comme au singulier (təʊ, t̬oʊ) ou différemment ?
- Faut-il utiliser un article/déterminant et faire les accords au masculin singulier (*le potatoes était délicieux*) ou au pluriel et dans ce cas s'agit-il d'un féminin (*les potatoes étaient délicieuses*) ; est-ce une forme de [réemprunt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9emprunt) de la [patate](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2082776) par métonymie ; a-t-on d'autre précisions sur l'usage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La prononciation habituelle en français est /**potetoz**/ sans diphtongues et avec des o ouverts ou fermés suivant les locuteurs.

Le pluriel est conservé et le genre féminin de *patate* est repris: **Les** potatoes étaient **délicieuses**.

Comme certains mots empruntés à l'anglais (un pins) ou à d'autres langues (un ravioli), le singulier ne respecte pas la grammaire originale et on entendra le plus souvent « **une potatoes** » plutôt que « **une potato** ».

Comment: /potetoz/, pas /potatoz/ ?

Comment: Oui, il doit bien y avoir quelques /a/ mais je n'ai jamais entendu que /e/.